# How to get a page_load or some event on parent page when I load a page in iframe using target in a hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, hyperlink, pageload

I have a asp.net page say **Admin.aspx** in which I have some hyper links. I have an iframe on the same page say **UserList.aspx**. When I click on any of the hyperlinks, I am opening the new page in the iframe.

```
....
 <li><a href="UserList.aspx   target="targetFrame" >UserList</a></li>
......
......
 <tr>           
   <td class="content">
     <iframe name="targetFrame" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" 
      style="" id="contentFrame"  runat="server"  src=""></iframe>
    </tr>
.....
 .....
```

Now I have a requirement so wherein I have to get the page load event of Admin.aspx when the user clicks on hyperlink. 
But presently I don't get any page load event. Where am I going wrong? What can I do to get the PageLoad event of parent?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to raise the page load event on the Admin page if you're delegating control to another page anyways? If you're transferring data from the Admin page you can post the data, or if you want to update application state use the session.

Anyways, you cannot raise a server side event from a user action on the client side you've got to ensure the hyperlink action is well for the lack of a better word, "detected" on the server end. You'll want to change the anchor links to asp:LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Basically I send a ajax request once any hyperlink is clicked and store the link in session so that I can access it later.

Thanks for the response !